# Why wont my Python code leave this while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

Im supposed to code a game that will ask random subtraction questions. When the user can enter 0 to continue to the next question, or -1 to exit. When it exits, it will print the users score and ask them if they want to play again. If the user gets 3 wrong answers in a row the game should end. However I can seem to get my while loop to work. It reaches 3 and then just resets. It never seems to end the game and ask the user if they want to play again.

What am I missing?

```
import random

highscore = 0

playAgain = 'Y'
while playAgain == 'Y':

correctCount = 0
totalCount = 0
wrongCount = 0

cont = 0
if wrongCount >=3:
    playAgain = eval(input("Do you want to play again? Y for Yes and N for No: "))
while wrongCount < 3:

    num1 = random.randint(0,9)
    num2 = random.randint(0,9)
    if num1 < num2:
        num1, num2 = num2, num1
        answer = eval(input("What is "+str(num1)+" - "+str(num2)+" ?\n"))
        if num1 - num2 == answer:
            print("You are correct!\n")
        totalCount += 1
        correctCount += 1

        #cont = int(input("Do you want to continue? 0 for Yes and -1 for No: "))
        if num1 - num2 != answer:
            print("Sorry, that answer is incorrect\n")
        totalCount += 1
        wrongCount += 1

score = (correctCount / totalCount) * 100
print("You answered "+correctCount+" questions right, out of a total of 
"+totalCount+" questions.\nYour score is: "+score)

if score > highscore:
print("You scored the new high score!")
playAgain = eval(input("Do you want to play again?"))
```

Comment: The indentation is off. Please make sure to copy the _real code_.

Comment: Under both the if statement, where you are incrementing the totalCount and correctCount, you need to indent it properly to work only under if condition, similarly when you incrementing totalCount and wrongCount in another if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is all that you want, enjoy...
note the correctCount and wrongCount with the if condition.

```
import random

highscore = 0

playAgain = 'Y'
while playAgain == 'Y':

    correctCount = 0
    totalCount = 0
    wrongCount = 0

    cont = 0
    # if wrongCount >=3:
    #     playAgain = int(input("Do you want to play again? Y for Yes and N for No: "))
    while wrongCount < 3:

        num1 = random.randint(0,9)
        num2 = random.randint(0,9)
        if num1 < num2:
            num1, num2 = num2, num1
            answer = int(input("What is " + str(num1)+ " - " + str(num2) + " ?\n"))
            if num1 - num2 == answer:
                print("You are correct!\n")
                correctCount += 1
            if num1 - num2 != answer:
                print("Sorry, that answer is incorrect\n")
                wrongCount += 1
            totalCount += 1

            #cont = int(input("Do you want to continue? 0 for Yes and -1 for No: "))            

    score = (correctCount / totalCount) * 100
    print("You answered "+str(correctCount)+" questions right, out of a total of "+str(totalCount)+" questions.\nYour score is: "+str(score))

    if score > highscore:
        highscore = score
        print("You scored the new high score!")
    playAgain = raw_input("Do you want to play again? Y for Yes and N for No: ")
```